# Farseer/Box2D - constrain rotation of Revolute Joint (or other) to one direction?

Tags: box2d, physics, farseer

I am trying to create a machine in Farseer (based on Box2D) which requires the use of one-way bearings so that a weight pivots around a point in an anti-clockwise only direction.

I have the weights attached using Revolute joints and everything is working apart from this issue.  I need the force of gravity on the weight to still affect the machine.  So it should swing out and not be able to swing back with the physics of the movement still there.

If anyone has any ideas as to how I could accomplish this I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Box2D doesn't come with this feature 'out of the box'. You could enable limits for the revolute joint, and adjust one of the limits to the current rotation every time step.

Comment: Yup. This technique can simulate the action of a ratcheting mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys, unfortunately this is not working for me.  There is a lot of inertia involved in the model and it seems as though this may be the reason for it not working.  I see other, slower models working, but still with some "flex" when limits are applied against inertia.  edit: specifically with applying limits, the objects with the limits applied to them go out of control when force is applied.  I am including the zero angle value in the range.